# How to setup SVN repository on svn://localhost/?

Tags: svn, repository

I created local SVN repository. Lets say it is `F:\svn\repository`

And I used `file:///F:/svn/repository` in TortoiseSVN to checkout that repository.

Now I want to use `svn://` protocol to make checkout and to make my repository available on `svn://localhost/repository`

So how can I setup existed SVN repository on `svn://localhost/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run `svnserve`, which acts as a server. From the SVN book:

> The svnserve program is a lightweight server, capable of speaking to clients over TCP/IP using a custom, stateful protocol. Clients contact an svnserve server by using URLs that begin with the svn:// or svn+ssh:// scheme

See more details about running configuring it [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html).